# Encoding issue with Shiny App and RStudio

Tags: r, shiny

I am having a problem at the time of publishing a Shiny app created in RStudio. Locally it works great, but at the time of publishing, i am getting the following error:

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 6271509...Detecting system locale ... DONE
Deploying bundle: 5891038 for application: 6271509 ...
Waiting for task: 1150562680
  building: Building image: 6880241
  building: Installing packages
  building: Installing files
  building: Pushing image: 6880241
  deploying: Starting instances
  success: Stopping old instances
Application successfully deployed to https://victuol.shinyapps.io/CorresponsalesSingleApp/
Deployment completed: https://victuol.shinyapps.io/CorresponsalesSingleApp/
Warning message:
Error detecting locale: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'raw'
 (Using default: en_US)
```

The following is my working code:

```
library(shiny)

library(DT)

setwd("C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/Proyecto Shiny Corresponsales")

library("openxlsx")

df<-read.xlsx("Base Datos Corresponsales Bancolombia LIMPIO Hoja 3.xlsx", sheet = 3,colNames = TRUE,cols=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))

ui <- basicPage(
  
  tags$a(
    href="https://lotopunto.negocio.site/", 
    tags$img(src = "Logo Loto Punto PNG.png", height = 260, width = 320, title = "Loto Punto Corresponsal Bancario")
      ),
  h2(strong("Paga, Juega y Recarga. ¡Todo aquí!")),
  h1("Mapa de Corresponsales Bancarios Bancolombia"),
  h3("Digita en la celda 'Search', la ciudad donde estás ubicado. 
  Se desplegarán los Corresponsales Bancarios Bancolombia disponibles"),
  
  
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    df
  
    })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am using an excel table, which have characters in Spanish (e.g. "'"). Might this be the problem? How can this be fixed? Please provide an example of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! All i had to do was to eliminate the following line:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/Proyecto Shiny Corresponsales")
```

I tried this solution, written at this post: https://groups.google.com/g/shinyapps-users/c/Fuh74H78G4s